# Como utilizar caracteres especiais para selecionar um elemento utilizando jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, seletores

Preciso verificar se um `input type=radio` foi checado com jQuery para passar para próxima etapa do formulário. Minha função para isso já estava funcionando, porém precisei transformar o name do `checkbox` em array para ela armazenar dados de todas as opções escolhidas.

Segue o código:

```
 $("#button-food").click(function() {
    var food = "";
    $('input:checkbox[name=food[]]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            food = $(this).val();
            console.log(food);
            
        }
    })
    console.log(food);
             
    if (food != "") {
        $("#food-page").hide();
        $("#drink-page").show();
    } else {
        alert("Você precisa escolher uma alternativa! Caso não coma nada, selecione a última opção.")
        $("#button-food").blur();
    }
    
    
})
```

O erro só apareceu depois que eu alterei o `name` dos *inputs* para `name="food[]"`, mudança que foi necessária para o back-end do site.
E a mensagem de erro do console foi a seguinte:

> ```
> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input:checkbox[name=food[]]
>     at Function.se.error (jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2)
>     at se.tokenize (jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2)
>     at se.select (jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2)
>     at Function.se [as find] (jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2)
>     at E.fn.init.find (jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2)
>     at new E.fn.init (jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2)
>     at E (jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2)
>     at HTMLInputElement. (quiz.js:43)
>     at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2)
>     at HTMLInputElement.v.handle (jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2)
> se.error @ jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2
> se.tokenize @ jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2
> se.select @ jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2
> se @ jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2
> find @ jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2
> E.fn.init @ jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2
> E @ jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2
> (anonymous) @ quiz.js:43
> dispatch @ jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2
> v.handle @ jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque você não pode colocar qualquer caractere como seletor. A [documentação](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) do jQuery destaca estes caracteres como "reservados" para seletores:

```
! "#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~
```

Desse modo, quando você tenta utilizar o seletor:

> ```
> //                      ↓↓
> input:checkbox[name=food[]]
> ```

Ele vai dar um erro — comparável a um erro de sintaxe em uma linguagem de programação. Afinal, o funcionamento é o mesmo. Precisa-se fazer uma análise sintática do seletor para que a biblioteca possa compreendê-lo, de modo que, ao encontrar um caractere "errado" (como, neste caso, um caractere reservado em posição inválida) o analisador não é capaz de prosseguir, já que há, evidentemente, um erro.

Para corrigir, você precisa informar que o trecho `[]` faz, de fato, parte do atributo `name`. Para isso, você pode escapá-los, utilizando o caractere de barra invertida (`\`) ou envolvê-los entre aspas:

```js
// Opção 1: Utilizar aspas para denotar corretamente o conteúdo do atributo `name`:
//                     ↓      ↓
$('input:checkbox[name="food[]"]');


// Opção 2: Escapar, com barra invertida, o caractere reservado:
//                         ↓↓ ↓↓
$('input:checkbox[name=food\\[\\]]');
```